# How do I get value of two digits in string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string, font-size

Suppose, I have the following string (no newlines in the original one):

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, [b]consectetur adipisici elit[/b],
sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et [fontSize=12]dolore [/fontSize=12] 
magna aliqua` in my textarea.
```

I'd like to extract the fontSize (12 in this case), any solution (including a regex one) is welcome.

Comment: @bobblebubble: My mistake, have corrected it.

Comment: @jan ty for  formatted my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [this rather simple pattern](https://regex101.com/r/rP7eD3/2):

```
\[fontSize=(\d+)\]
# will look for fontSize= in square brackets 
# and captures the digits found
```

In JavaScript Code, this would be:

```
var regex = /\[fontSize=(\d+)\]/;
var str = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, [b]consectetur adipisici elit[/b], sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et [fontSize=12]dolore [/fontSize=12] magna aliqua";
var match = regex.exec(str);
var fontSize = match[1];
print(fontSize);
```

See [a demo on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/uBF03v).